# R Shiny App for Data Visualization

Tags: r, bar-chart, shiny

I am trying to create a R shiny App for my data visualization. The data looks like

```
ID  route_id    trip_id direction   boarding    alighting   load
192197  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  68  0   167
192198  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  4   0   171
192199  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  4   0   175
192200  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  1   0   176
192201  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  3   0   179
192202  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  9   0   188
192203  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  0   0   188
192204  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  1   0   189
192205  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  1   0   190
192206  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  0   0   190
192207  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  1   0   191
192208  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  0   0   191
192209  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  4   0   195
192210  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  0   0   195
192211  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  3   0   198
192212  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  14  0   212
192213  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  0   23  189
192214  760-76  8223726-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_760__Express_/_Downtown  0   27  162
194205  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   15  0   154
194206  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   0   154
194207  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   0   154
194208  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   0   154
194209  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   0   154
194210  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   0   154
194211  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   0   154
194212  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   15  0   169
194213  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   0   165
194214  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   1   4   166
194215  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   0   166
194216  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   1   0   167
194217  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   3   0   170
194218  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   7   163
194219  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   2   161
194220  589-76  8224010-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Northbound_589__Express_/_Minneapolis   0   9   152
313432  852-76  8227043-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_852__Express_/_Northtown_/_Dntn_Mpls 21  0   151
313433  852-76  8227043-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_852__Express_/_Northtown_/_Dntn_Mpls 0   0   151
313434  852-76  8227043-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_852__Express_/_Northtown_/_Dntn_Mpls 0   0   151
313435  852-76  8227043-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_852__Express_/_Northtown_/_Dntn_Mpls 6   0   157
313616  852-76  8227045-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_852__Express_/_Northtown_/_Dntn_Mpls 53  0   183
313617  852-76  8227045-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_852__Express_/_Northtown_/_Dntn_Mpls 0   0   183
313618  852-76  8227045-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_852__Express_/_Northtown_/_Dntn_Mpls 0   0   183
313619  852-76  8227045-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_852__Express_/_Northtown_/_Dntn_Mpls 9   0   192
313620  852-76  8227045-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_852__Express_/_Northtown_/_Dntn_Mpls 0   24  168
325301  21-76   8227241-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_21__Selby-Lake/_Uptown    18  0   160
325302  21-76   8227241-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_21__Selby-Lake/_Uptown    2   0   162
325303  21-76   8227241-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_21__Selby-Lake/_Uptown    0   0   162
325304  21-76   8227241-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_21__Selby-Lake/_Uptown    6   7   161
325305  21-76   8227241-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_21__Selby-Lake/_Uptown    6   2   165
325306  21-76   8227241-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_21__Selby-Lake/_Uptown    5   2   168
325307  21-76   8227241-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_21__Selby-Lake/_Uptown    18  12  174
325308  21-76   8227241-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_21__Selby-Lake/_Uptown    4   5   169
325309  21-76   8227241-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_21__Selby-Lake/_Uptown    0   4   169
325310  21-76   8227241-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_21__Selby-Lake/_Uptown    0   0   169
352204  94-76   8227923-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_94_Express_/_Downtown_/_Minneapolis   55  0   155
352398  94-76   8227934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_94_Express_/_Downtown_/_Minneapolis   52  0   170
352399  94-76   8227934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_94_Express_/_Downtown_/_Minneapolis   0   11  159
352400  94-76   8227934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_94_Express_/_Downtown_/_Minneapolis   0   2   157
352674  94-76   8227949-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_94_Express_/_Downtown_/_Minneapolis   37  0   162
352675  94-76   8227949-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Westbound_94_Express_/_Downtown_/_Minneapolis   0   10  152
390699  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 48  1   164
390700  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 2   0   166
390701  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 3   0   169
390702  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 3   1   171
390703  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   171
390704  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 4   0   175
390705  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 16  0   191
390706  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   191
390707  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 12  0   203
390708  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 1   0   204
390709  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 4   11  197
390710  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   197
390711  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 7   4   200
390712  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 1   3   198
390713  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   1   197
390714  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   187
390715  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 6   10  193
390716  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 2   1   194
390717  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   194
390718  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   2   184
390719  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   8   184
390720  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   9   175
390721  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 1   0   176
390722  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   176
390723  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 3   4   165
390724  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   10  165
390725  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   2   163
390726  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   2   161
390727  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   2   159
390728  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   159
390729  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   3   153
390730  22-76   8270934-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   3   153
390817  22-76   8270935-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 11  0   158
390818  22-76   8270935-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   158
390819  22-76   8270935-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   158
390820  22-76   8270935-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   158
390821  22-76   8270935-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 2   0   160
390822  22-76   8270935-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   160
390823  22-76   8270935-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   160
392402  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 20  0   170
392403  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   170
392404  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   8   162
392405  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   162
392406  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   3   159
392407  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   159
392408  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   159
392409  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   152
392410  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   7   152
392411  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   152
392412  22-76   8270947-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_22H__Cedar-28Av/VA_Med_Ctr/Via_Dupont-57 0   0   152
415001  17-76   8339808-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17__Downtown  27  0   169
415002  17-76   8339808-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17__Downtown  0   0   169
415003  17-76   8339808-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17__Downtown  0   5   164
415004  17-76   8339808-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17__Downtown  3   0   167
415005  17-76   8339808-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17__Downtown  0   0   167
415006  17-76   8339808-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17__Downtown  0   0   167
415007  17-76   8339808-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17__Downtown  0   0   167
415008  17-76   8339808-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17__Downtown  0   0   167
415009  17-76   8339808-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17__Downtown  0   0   166
415010  17-76   8339808-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17__Downtown  0   1   166
422541  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  35  0   160
422542  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  0   1   159
422543  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  2   0   161
422544  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  34  0   195
422545  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  3   0   198
422546  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  2   5   195
422547  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  0   6   189
422548  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  1   0   190
422549  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  1   3   188
422550  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  0   0   187
422551  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  0   1   187
422552  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  0   1   184
422553  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  2   2   186
422554  17-76   8339910-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Eastbound_17W__Wash_St_NE_/_To_27th_NE  0   30  156
441158  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 49  0   153
441159  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 5   0   158
441160  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 0   0   158
441161  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 3   0   161
441162  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 0   0   161
441163  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 0   0   161
441164  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 1   0   162
441165  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 0   0   162
441166  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 0   0   162
441167  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 0   0   162
441168  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 0   0   162
441169  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 0   0   162
441170  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 0   0   162
441171  724-76  8346221-MAR15-MVS-BUS-Weekday-01    Southbound_724_Brklyn_Ctr_/_Transit_Ctr 0   0   162
```

So the following is my ui.R The file takes input from the user for route_id, and then creatw bar graph for eg. load for various stop_id.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel('FAST_TRIPS Visulization', windowTitle = "Fast_trips Visaualization"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('route', 'Choose the Route No.', unique(y['route_id'])),
      selectInput('id', 'Please Choose Stop or Trip ID', c('stop_id','trip_id')),
      selectInput('rider', 'What do you wanna compare?', c('boarding', 'alighting', 'load')),
      radioButtons('method','Please select your method', c('Sum', 'Average'))),
    mainPanel(

      plotOutput('plot1')

    )
  )
)
```

and my server.R is follwing

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame



  selectedData <- reactive({
    y[c('route_id', input$id, input$rider)]

  })

  data <- reactive({
    subset(selectedData(), route_id == input$route)
  })


  a <- reactive({
    aggregate(input$rider~input$id,data,sum)
  })



  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({barplot(a[input$rider])})

}
```

Every time I run this app. i get the following error:

```
object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

I am new in creating R shiny app. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try rewriting `server.R` in the following way:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Combine the selected variables into a new data frame
  data <- reactive({
    subset(y, route_id == input$route, 
        select = c('route_id', input$id, input$rider))
  })
  a <- reactive({
    aggregate(as.formula(paste0(input$rider, "~", input$id)), data(), sum)
  })  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    barplot(a()[,input$rider])
  })
}
```

---

*Explanation.* There are several problems with the code, but as far as I can tell, the problem that gives rise to your error message is that you did not specify your reactive functions (e.g. `data`, `a`) with parentheses, e.g. in your calls to `aggregate` and `barplot`.

Another error is that you call `aggregate` using the formula construct, but `input$rider~input$id` is actually something like `"boarding"~"trip_id"`, rather than `boarding~trip_id`. I amended this using `as.formula(paste0(...))`.

Third, `barplot` takes a vector or matrix for its `height` argument, but using `a()[input$rider]` gives you a dataframe; instead, use `a()[, input$rider]` (with the comma).

Fourth, in your `ui.R`, you have a `stop_id` option, but this column doesn't actually exist in your dataframe. I didn't change it since it produces a warning but does not kill your app.

Fifth, note that you can filter and select columns with a single call to `subset`.

You should get an output like this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks You very much. I know there were lot of issues with my code. May be I should learn R syntax more.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and happy to help. If this answer resolved your question, please mark it as accepted.